# Using Linq to select results into a new instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this linq query that I am using to join two tables from the _gameContext.

I'm trying to use `select` to create a new object of type GameScoresDto.

But I keep getting a message that GameScoresDto does not have a constructor that take 5 arguments.

I know what the error means, but I thought there was a way to use `select` to select results into a new object.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
[HttpGet("GameScores/{gameId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<GameScoresDto>>> GameScores(Guid gameID)
{
    //var gameScores = await _gameContext.CurrentScores.Where(c => c.GameId == gameID).ToListAsync();

    var gameScores = await (from cs in _gameContext.CurrentScores
                join sm in _gameContext.ScoreMax
                on cs.CurrentScoreId equals sm.CurrentScoreId
                where cs.GameId == gameID
                select 
                    new GameScoresDto ( 
                    cs.ScoreId,
                    cs.GameId,
                    cs.InitialValue,
                    cs.MaximumValue,
                    sm.ActionAmount
                ).ToListAsync();

    return gameScores;
}
```

Comment: It means that you're trying to call the `GameScoresDto` constructor with `5` arguments (ScoreId, GameId, InitialValue, MaximumValue, and ActionAmount), but there is not constructor defined for that type that takes `5` arguments.

Comment: Without seeing GameScoresDto, it's hard to tell, but my guess is it has 5 properties, in that order, and you expect to simply pass it in order to fill those properties. Try using curly braces and setting the properties by name, if that's the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you're trying to call the `GameScoresDto` constructor with `5` arguments (ScoreId, GameId, InitialValue, MaximumValue, and ActionAmount), but there is no constructor defined for that type that takes `5` arguments.

To resolve this issue, either create a constructor that takes in these `5` arguments:

```
public class GameScoreDTO
{
    public GameScoreDTO(int scoreId, int gameId, int initVal, int maxVal, int actionAmt)
    {
        // Set properties from constructor arguments here
    }

    // Other class code omitted
}
```

or use object initializer syntax instead:

```
select new GameScoresDto 
{
    ScoreId = cs.ScoreId,
    GameId = cs.GameId,
    InitialValue = cs.InitialValue,
    MaximumValue = cs.MaximumValue,
    ActionAmount = sm.ActionAmount
}
```

(the code samples above assume that `GameScoresDto` has the specified properties)

Comment: Thanks! That solved every problem except the ending where I have `.ToListAsync();`  It says `GameScoresDto does not contain a definition for ToListAsync`.

Comment: Try adding the closing `)` for the `Select` before calling ToListAsync()`